# Laravel Artisan queue:work poor performance on Kubernetes

Tags: laravel, performance, kubernetes, rabbitmq, amazon-eks

Trying to figure out the performance issue with Laravel application on EKS after migration. Thank you in advance for any comments and interest in this problem.

## UPDATES

(10.01.2023) - we moved the cache driver from Filesystem (which was powered by EFS) to Redis. The performance of workloads increased in 8 times. But it is still much less than was on legacy architecture.

## Stack

**Infra**

- Kubernetes v1.24
- EKS BOTTLEROCKET_x86_64, t3a.xlarge (managed nodegroup)
- AMI release version: 1.11.1-104f8e0f (managed nodegroup)
- Cilium v1.12.4 with kube-proxy replacement
- Hubble enabled
- EFS as PV storage class

**Problematic application**

- Laravel v6.20.44
- PHP CLI: 7.2.24-cli-alpine3.10
- PHP FPM: 7.2.24-fpm-alpine3.10
- RabbitMQ 3.11.4, Erlang 25.1.2
- vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq v10.2.3

## Context

Currently I am moving legacy infrastructure from native one-server LAMP stack to Kubernetes on EKS. The project is periodically high loaded by scheduled synchronization processes. I developed Helm chart to deploy each Laravel queue worker in separate container to allow then automate scaling which can be triggered by different events.

I already moved 2 applications with same stack as **Problematic application** to EKS cluster with no issues related to performance. But with third there is a **Problem**.

**Problematic application** on legacy environment was working on t3.medium (2 vCPU, 4 RAM). After moving it to EKS the instance type that compute application's workloads is not changed.

## Problem

Application has several queues in RabbitMQ for daily synchronization process. On legacy infrastructure, the average speed of acknowledging Jobs in queue **A** was **240/s** (4 consumers). After migration to Kuberneіtes, we observed downgrade of speed to **5.2/s** (4 consumers).

> P.S. - other queues' speed had degraded too. Queue **A** is taken as an example.

The application source code has not changed since the migration.

### Benchmark

We did benchmarking of `handle` method in Jobs that are processed in the queue **A**. The function is processed under 50ms, so there is no actual problem with written business logic. But still there is a question where all other time is gone...

### Monitoring

After monitoring (Grafana + Prometheus) I discovered, that queue workers do not hit the resource limits, and actually are using under 50m of CPU, when configuration is requesting 150m. So there seems like no problem with resource allocation, but performance is still poor. Please correct me if I am missing something.

## Tried Solutions

1. Created separate node group with `t3a.xlarge` instance type, performance increased from **5.2/s** to **60/s** for queue **A**. But for other queue, for ex. **B**, there is not big difference in performance: throughput **220/s** (legacy) vs **12/s** (EKS on t3a.xlarge).
2. Increased allocated resources for each queue worker pod (tried to increase CPU and RAM), but the average worker speed is not changing. Tried even allocate 1 vCPU per each queue worker pod, but no luck.
3. Increased replicas of consumers from 4 20, had increased throughput from **5.2/s** to **12/s**, but after increasing replicas even more -> could not achieve the speed more than **12/s**.
4. Changed `php artisan queue:work` to `php artisan rabbitmq:consume`, because queue:work set prefetch count in RabbitMQ connection to 1. But it does not cause any performance improvements.

## Expected Behavior

The main question is what is the difference between environments and where is the bottleneck.

Network limits are the same between legacy and Kubernetes environment, 5 Gigabit. So I am not sure that problem is within network throughput.

As the result of the research and investigation I expect to have at least the same performance for all queues workers on EKS that we had on legacy environment.

Comment: Anything in the cilium logs? Also i recommend always use EKS best practices https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/reliability/docs/networkmanagement/